# RSA encryption using modulus and exponent public key

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I need to encrypt my steam login password. Before sending the auth data, steam sends this: "publickey_mod":"c511d72db5ebbba01977983eec2...","publickey_exp":"010001".

The browser encrypts password with this script:

```
var pubKey = RSA.getPublicKey(results.publickey_mod, results.publickey_exp);
password = password.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, ''); // remove non-standard-ASCII characters
var encryptedPassword = RSA.encrypt(password, pubKey);
```

I can't write a working algorithm in c# which will encrypt the password using modulus and exponent.

Here is what i tried:

```
        static async Task Main()
        {
            
            var pubKey = SetPublicKey($"{response["publickey_mod"]}", $"{response["publickey_exp"]}");
            

            string password = "123456";
            byte[] password_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

            byte[] encryptedPassword;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                RSA.ImportParameters(pubKey);
                encryptedPassword = RSA.Encrypt(password_byte, false);
            }

            string encodingPassword = Convert.ToHexString(encryptedPassword);

            Console.WriteLine(encodingPassword);
        }
        public static RSAParameters SetPublicKey(string modulus, string exponent)
        {
            RSAParameters result = new RSAParameters();
            result.Modulus = Convert.FromHexString(modulus);
            result.Exponent = Convert.FromHexString(exponent);

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? what doesn't work? RSA is pretty well documented in .net

Comment: @zaitsman when trying to encrypt, I got a "bad data" error, most likely I'm converting the key incorrectly. In the documentation, I did not find something specific that suits me.

Comment: @zaitsman I added in question, what I tried.

Comment: If you’re using values you have in the sample they are NOT b64 encoded so your code won’t work

Comment: @zaitsman I fix this, but error "bad data" on the line RSA.ImportParameters(pubKey); remained

Comment: Modulus and public exponent seem to be hex encoded, you have to hex decode them, e.g. with `Convert.FromHexString()`.

Comment: I fixed this and something else, seems to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

working algorithm:

```
            
            byte[] encryptedPasswordBytes;
            using (var rsaEncryptor = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
                var rsaParameters = rsaEncryptor.ExportParameters(false);
                rsaParameters.Exponent = Convert.FromHexString($"{_response_getrsakey["publickey_exp"]}");
                rsaParameters.Modulus = Convert.FromHexString($"{_response_getrsakey["publickey_mod"]}");
                rsaEncryptor.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
                encryptedPasswordBytes = rsaEncryptor.Encrypt(passwordBytes, false);
            }

            string encryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedPasswordBytes);
```